# Waiting for cancelled async method from UI thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, deadlock, cancellation-token

I have a WPF program appending to a textbox asynchronously.
If the user selects a new provider via combobox, the appending should be cancelled and called again with the new provider. problem is the updateMoviesTask?.Wait() deadlocks.
I guess it is because UpdateMovies() waits for ui thread and ProviderId property waits for the task. How can I solve this?

```
CancellationTokenSource source;
Task updateMoviesTask;

async Task UpdateMovies()
{
    source?.Dispose();
    source = new CancellationTokenSource();

    CancellationToken cancel = source.Token;

    var request = new GetPopularRequest(Country.Germany);

    for (int i = 1; i <= TotalPages; i++)
    {
        request.Page = i;
        request.ProviderId = providerId;

        var getPopularResponse = await justWatchClient.GetPopularAsync(request);

        // do ui stuff here        

        if (cancel.IsCancellationRequested)
            return;
    }
}

public GetProviderResponse ProviderId
{
    get { return providerId; }
    set
    {
        this.providerId = value; 
        this.source?.Cancel();
        updateMoviesTask?.Wait();
        updateMoviesTask = this.UpdateMovies();
        this.OnPropertyChanged("");
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `updateMoviesTask?.ContinueWith( ()=> updateMoviesTask = this.UpdateMovies())` without blocking. And I wonder why are you waiting for the canceled task? And also if `justWatchClient` is an HTTP client you can forward the `CancellationToken` to the client so if there is any ongoing request it could be canceled too.

Comment: When I would start the new task before the old one is completed then they both would interfer each other (appending stuff to the same textbox etc.)

Comment: the JustWatch API does not seem to support CancellationToken

Comment: I tried 'updateMoviesTask.ContinueWith(_ => updateMoviesTask = this.UpdateMovies());' but then I get an exception from UpdateMovies because it was not started from UI thread so I would now have to dispatch UI accesses. This would defeat the purpose of async/await, right?

Comment: `This would defeat the purpose of async/await, right?` maybe not entirely but it is indeed not a good design. I would change your design into something like this: Make your property just emits an event like ProviderIdChanged. Inside the event handler run the `UpdateMovies` method. Have a flag `CanChangeProviderId` inside the setter check that flag to set the value and fire the event. Also, you can bind your button to that flag so it will prevent pressing the button many times. Control the flag inside the handler or in the setter method.

Comment: Never call `Wait` on a Task object. Instead await it: `await updateMoviesTask` or `await UpdateMovies()`. `Task.Wait` will synchronously wait for tghe task to complete and therefore blocking the caller's context which will prevent the asyn method to return (deadlock). `await` should fix your issue.

Comment: You shouldn't execute long running operations or async methods from a property set() or get(). That's a code smell. Simply call the cancellation method from the code that sets the property. In case the property is set from the UI then use a ICommand to cancel the async operation.

Comment: Now I understand that your `updateMoviesTask.Wait` code part is only there to wait for the cancellation? That's not necessary at all (this code doesn't even behave as you expect). Somewhere in your code you call `await UpdateMovies()`. When you cancel the async operation the code will continue to execute the remaining code after the `await UpdateMovies()`. Once the caller has returned the synchronous `CancellationToken.Cancel()` context will continue.

Comment: @BionicCode: I cannot await from inside a property, right?

Comment: @Eldar: How can a flag help me? I want that the user can change the Provider at any time, even when the getting of the old data is still running, then it should be cancelled. the user is never required to wait.

Comment: That's correct. This fact is a good indicator that you shouldn't handle async code in properties. That's why I made some suggestions on how to refactor your code to eliminate the code smell. But most important, you don't have to await anythig at all in this context. or is the property the actual code that invokes the UpdateMovies method?

Comment: Ok, UpdateMovies uses the ProviderId value? And when it changes you want to restart the update process?

Comment: How does the user modify the ProviderId proeprty?

Comment: @BionicCode: the provider id combobox has a databinding to the ProviderId property.

Comment: And selecting the ComboBox value also triggers the update? You cancel the running operation (in case there is one) and start a new request?

Comment: @BionicCode: Yes, as you see it in my code. Sure I could attach an propertychanged handler to the property and call the method from there, but IMHO this would not change anything substantial?

Comment: Yes I wasn't expecting this. Let me post an answer to highlight a better UX that also avoids to start async operations from the property.

Comment: Where is the code located? Do you use MVVM or is this part of a control's code-behind?

Comment: @BionicCode: the code is all in the question. Sure it is not compileable, but it is the relevant part.

Comment: I want to kn0w where the code is located. is it in the code-behind or do you u se a view model class. in other words, what is the DataContext?

Comment: Ok, never mind. i wanted to create an example. This is my point (from my original answer I was writing):

Comment: Good UX would require the user to start such long running operations explicitly. Selecting an value from an innocent `ComboBox` shouldn't result in a resource intensive surprise. Instead let the user configure the operation (e.g. select the `ProviderId` and start it by clicking in a e.g. "Update" button. Now everything is transparent to the user. You could even allow the user to decide whether he wants to wait for completion or to abort the running operation.

Comment: @BionicCode: the code is from the viewmodel.

Comment: Then call the UpdateMovies from an ICommand handler or from the "Update" button Click event handler.

Comment: this.OnPropertyChanged("") or this.OnPropertyChanged(null) will raise PropertyChanged for all properties of the owning type. This can be quite inefficient. Al binding targets will be forced to refresh and all PropertyChanged observes will be invoked.

Comment: Have a look @ [ReactiveUI - Compelling Example](https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/getting-started/compelling-example) which shows how to start/cancel a task when a property has changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, then you need to - Look at this version of the code (without taking into account the handling of possible exceptions):

```cs
    private CancellationTokenSource source = new();
    private readonly object locker = new();

    private void UpdateMovies() => Task.Run(() =>
    {
        source.Dispose();
        source = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken cancel = source.Token;

        lock (locker)
        {
            var request = new GetPopularRequest(Country.Germany);

            for (int i = 1; i <= TotalPages; i++)
            {
                request.Page = i;
                request.ProviderId = providerId;

                // Need a synchronous version of the method
                // var getPopularResponse = await justWatchClient.GetPopularAsync(request);
                var getPopularResponse = justWatchClient.GetPopular(request);

                // do ui stuff here        

                if (cancel.IsCancellationRequested)
                    return;
            }
        }
    });

    public GetProviderResponse ProviderId
    {
        get { return providerId; }
        set
        {
            this.providerId = value;
            UpdateMovies();
            this.OnPropertyChanged(string.Empty);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can I still do UI stuff inside Task.Run()? I would have to use the Dispatcher.Invoke, right?

Comment: So you suggest to use a lock statement to wait for the other task to finish. Since this is running in a separate thread I guess UI will not block during lock contention

Comment: @codymanix, You can work with DispatcherObject (including UI-element) only in the thread in which they were created. Dispatcher.Invoke is one way to execute code on an  UI-element's thread.

Comment: Since you have a non-shared resource, it is more logical and easier to use a locking when accessing it than to track the completion of all methods that can work with it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your flow is as follows: user modifies the `ProviderId` property. The property then cancels any running `UpdatMovies` operations and start a new.

Good UX would require the user to start such long running operations explicitly. Selecting an value from an innocent `ComboBox` shouldn't result in a resource intensive surprise. Instead let the user configure the opeartion (e.g. select the `ProviderId` and start it by clicking in a e.g. "Update" button. Now everything is transparent to the user. You could even allow the user to decide whether he wants to wait for completion or to abort the running operation.

```xml
<Window>
  <StackPanel>
    <CombBox SelectedItem={Binding ProviderId}" />
    <Button Content="Start update"
            Command="{Binding UpdateMoviesCommand}" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

See [Microsoft Docs: Relaying Command Logic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern#relaying-command-logic) for the `RelayCommand` implementation used in the example.

```cs
public object ProviderId { get; set; }
public ICommand UpdateMoviesCommand => new RelayCommand(ExecuteUpdateMoviesCommand, CanExecuteUpdateMoviesCommand);
private CancellationTokenSource CancellationTokenSource { get; set; }  
  = new CancellationTokenSource();
private SemaphoreSlim Semaphore { get; }
  = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

private bool CanExecuteUpdateMoviesCommand(object commandParameter)
  => this.ProviderId is not null;

private async void ExecuteUpdateMoviesCommand(object commandParameter)
{
  this.CancellationTokenSource.Cancel();

  // Asynchronously wait until UpdateMoviesAsync has returned 
  // and the finally block was executed to allow the current context to continue.
  await this.Semaphore.WaitAsnyc();
  
  try
  {  
    await UpdateMoviesAsync(this.CancellationTokenSource.Token);
  }
  catch (OperationCanceledException)
  {
  }   
  finally 
  {    
    this.CancellationTokenSource.Dispose();
    this.CancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    // Allow the waiting context to call UpdateMoviesAsync
    this.Semaphore.Release();
  }
}

private async Task UpdateMoviesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  var request = new GetPopularRequest(Country.Germany);

  for (int i = 1; i <= TotalPages; i++)
  {
    request.Page = i;
    request.ProviderId = providerId;

    // Consider to make justWatchClient.GetPopularAsync 
    // cancellable too to improve performance
    var getPopularResponse = await justWatchClient.GetPopularAsync(request);

    // do ui stuff here        

    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
  }
}
```

Alternatively, use the `ComboBox.SelectionChanged` event to trigger the async operation.

Comment: how is guaranteed that UpdateMoviesAsync is not still running when it is newly started? Cancelling the token signals the cancellation but it is not necessarily finished after that call?

Comment: I have updated the answer to show how to asynchronously wait using a SemaphoreSlim.

Answer (score 0):

> If the user selects a new provider via combobox, the appending should be cancelled and called again with the new provider. problem is the updateMoviesTask?.Wait() deadlocks. I guess it is because UpdateMovies() waits for ui thread and ProviderId property waits for the task. How can I solve this?

Yes, that's a [classic deadlock](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) I describe on my blog.

With these kinds of "replace the operation updating the UI" problems, I generally prefer a token-based approach. Every operation is handed a token, and only updates the UI if its token matches the current token. Then, when starting a new operation, regenerate the token before passing it to the new operation.

In old-school code, I've just used something as simple as `object` as the token, but these days a `CancellationToken` is just as good. And, in fact, *your code already has one*; it just has to observe it anytime *before* it updates the UI.

Side note: sometimes you have to wait for the previous operation to complete, e.g., if it's updating some external resource like a database or cache and you don't want it interfering with the current operation. But if the operations only do some queries and update the UI, then waiting for the previous operation to complete is not necessary; you can just regenerate the token and start the replacement operation immediately.

```
CancellationTokenSource source;

async Task UpdateMoviesAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
{
  var request = new GetPopularRequest(Country.Germany);

  for (int i = 1; i <= TotalPages; i++)
  {
    request.Page = i;
    request.ProviderId = providerId;

    var getPopularResponse = await justWatchClient.GetPopularAsync(request);

    if (cancel.IsCancellationRequested)
      return;

    // do ui stuff here
  }
}

public GetProviderResponse ProviderId
{
  get { return providerId; }
  set
  {
    providerId = value; 
    source?.Cancel();
    source?.Dispose();
    source = new CancellationTokenSource();
    _ = this.UpdateMoviesAsync(source.Token); // see note below
    this.OnPropertyChanged("");
  }
}
```

Discarding the task `_ = ...` is problematic. It's actually ignoring any errors that can come from `UpdateMoviesAsync`. And making `UpdateMoviesAsync` `async void` instead of `async Task` would be even worse - you'd crash on errors. You'll want to handle this better than either of these approaches. My recommended pattern is the "notify task" pattern, which takes a `Task` and makes it observable (including exceptions). The Notify Task pattern is described in [this article of mine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/march/async-programming-patterns-for-asynchronous-mvvm-applications-data-binding?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058). Note that these days most MVVM libraries have some kind of `NotifyTask<T>` built-in, though it sometimes goes by different names.